# Modifie common shoes to ESD acceptable

Tags: esd

I've a problem where I for the moment can't use my ESD shoes because off ergonomic reasons. So I wonder if anyone have a good temporary suggestion on how to add ESD protection to some normal shoes for ESD protection?

The floor I walk on is concrete.

I've thought a bit on how it could be done.
My own idea is to strap some conductive material to the leg and then attach it to a resistor which later on is connected to a pad I attach under the sole of my normal shoes. I have no clue on what material to use though if this now is an eligible solution.

I hope someone can give me some tips
Best regards

Comment: Don't make your own, you can buy these things: http://www.esdshop.eu/pictures/vyrobky/1obr_860.jpeg  Also, if you want **proper** ESD protection that concrete floor might need some form of conductive coating otherwise, the shoe strap makes little sense by itself.

Comment: What are the ergonomic reasons? Don't they fit?

Comment: Maybe the wrong colour?

Comment: Wear leather soled shoes, wear cotton (or linen) clothing and socks.  Avoid synthetic fibers, wool, and silk.

Comment: Get  2 meters of grounding-braid, the heavy sort, used to strap together system chassis to survive lightning strikes. Wrap 2/3 meter around your bare ankles, perhaps shaving the skin first to ensure good contact. Solder the overlapped heavy braid; perhaps use chemlab asbestos pad under the soldering points. You now have a fine (temporary) contact with your body; if the skin abrades under the braid and an actual ohmic connection results, you've further increases the ESD control of your environment. Finally, connect a 22,000,000 Ohm resistor (red red blue) from braid to Ground.

Comment: @Anton They make ESD ankles straps for normal shoes. But that doesn't matter. What matters is the standards that you are required to maintain in you ESD area (if any)

Answer (score 3):

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Those are called ESD shoe straps.